# Work-arounds for GraphicsData not showing in Wolfram Cloud?

Tags: graphics, wolfram-cloud

I often copy-paste things from LatexIt or OmniGraffle into Mathematica notebooks. The results are `GraphicsData` objects which don't render in the Wolfram Cloud. Is there an easy work-around?

Since bitmaps render properly, perhaps there's some way to automatically convert all `GraphicsData` objects in the notebook into bitmaps?

Here's example notebook:

https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/graphics-data-example.nb

How it looks locally

[image]

Comment: You should email WRI about this bug

Comment: It's not a bug per se, just a really old Mac behavior.  Those programs are emitting PDF to the clipboard instead of a bitmap.  And the Mac FE was the only one really capable of handling that particular format.  For instance, the Windows FE is not capable of rendering those cells either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to convert the given [`GraphicsData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsData) objects into vector graphics, but you can use [`Rasterize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize) to convert them into bitmaps. Here is a function that does this:

```
rasterizeGraphicsData[Cell[g:GraphicsData["PDF", __], "Graphics", OptionsPattern[Cell]]] := Module[{size},
    size = OptionValue[Cell, ImageSize];
    Cell[
        BoxData @ ToBoxes @ Rasterize[
            Cell[g, "Graphics"], 
            ImageSize -> size,
            RasterSize -> 5 size
        ],
        "Output"
    ]
]
```

Now, we need to apply the above function on each of the [`GraphicsData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsData) cells. We can do that with the following function:

```
convertNotebookGraphicsData[nb_] := With[
    {cells = Cells[nb, CellStyle -> "Graphics"]},
    NotebookWrite[#, rasterizeGraphicsData @ NotebookRead[#]]& /@ cells
]
```

Use [`Notebooks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Notebooks) to find the notebook object to process and then use `convertNotebookGraphicsData[nb]` where `nb` is the [`NotebookObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookObject) corresponding to your notebook.